# Using private docker registry for GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com) and would like to build my project with the provided shared runners.

I have a docker image which contains all dependencies to build the project. The image is located at `privateregistry.example.com`. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```
image: privateregistry.example.com/myteam/myimage

before_script:
  - npm install

build:
  script:
    # ...
```

Since it is a private registry, I followed the [instructions provided by gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#using-a-private-container-registry) and created under `Settings -> Variables` a variable `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`, and used the contents of my local `~/.docker/config.json` as value.

However, gitlab is not able to pull my image:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.8.0-rc.1 (1fd3fd4)
Using Docker executor with image privateregistry.example.com/myteam/myimage ...
Pulling docker image privateregistry.example.com/myteam/myimage ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: unauthorized: authentication required
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If your secret contains unprintable characters you can also hit  an issue with escaping of special characters. Special characters that may mess you up include $ and % and ^ and ~ and others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't do anything wrong. Today, after clicking on "Rebuild", it just works.

**Edit:** Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. Thanks to gitlab.com for beeing reliable, guess I will need to setup my own runners.

Comment: It would be clearer if you said "Gitlab.com" when you mean "the public gitlab at gitlab.com".  Gitlab is a program that can be installed on your own server. Gitlab.com is a public service using that program.